# ASP.NET CORE MVC | System.ArgumentNullException : 'Value cannot be null. ' | Configuration.GetConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, connection-string, appsettings

I'm using MVC on Asp.NET Core, & actually, the Startup doesn't find my ConnectionString written the appsettings.json. I've already tried in 3 different ways (2 in comments). Do not pay attention about the "XXX"s.

Let's see :
**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    [...]
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Web")));
    //options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["Web"]));
    //options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetSection("Web")["ConnectionString"]));
    [...]
}
```

**appsettings.json** :

```json
[...]
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Test1": {
        "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XX.XX.X.XXX)(PORT=XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;",
            "ProviderName": "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
    },
    "Web": {
        "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XX.XX.X.XXX)(PORT=XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;",
            "ProviderName": "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
    },
    "Test2": {
        "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XX.XX.X.XXX)(PORT=XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;",
            "ProviderName": "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
    }
}
[...]
```

& when I build the project to run in the browser, I've always got this error :

**System.ArgumentNullException : 'Value cannot be null. '**

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `IServiceCollection.GetConnectionString` just add the prefix `ConnectionStrings:` in the key.

Then `Configuration.GetConnectionString("Web")` is similar to `Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Web"]`.

In your case, you need :

```cs
Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Web:ConnectionString"]
//or
Configuration.GetConnectionString("Web:ConnectionString")
```

Comment: Exactly. You're absolutely right. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

Yes! you need to add Test1/Web/Test2 ..

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Web:ConnectionString")));
```

}

Comment: Thank you ! I got it know !